# 403 Forbidden when authorizing in multitenancy keycloak with credentials

Tags: java, spring-boot, keycloak

I was trying to follow the same multitenancy setup as the official [documentation](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-documentation/blob/main/securing_apps/topics/oidc/java/multi-tenancy.adoc), but with credentials in my keycloak.json file, but keycloak does not seem to authorize access token properly.

It appears to call the resolve function of my customized KeycloakConfigResolver multiple times. It does authorize the token at the first time it calls to resolve, but it then shows 'Failed to verify token' every time after that.

And at the end, it fails to verify my access token.

Using customized keycloakconfigresolver in realms with credentials result in 403 Forbidden error.

```
@Configuration
public class HeaderBasedConfigResolver implements KeycloakConfigResolver {

  @Override
  public KeycloakDeployment resolve(Request request) {
    System.out.println("Start Header-based resolving");
    String realm = request.getHeader("realm");
    File file = new File("realm_json/" + realm + "-keycloak.json");
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
      is = new FileInputStream(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return KeycloakDeploymentBuilder.build(is);
  }

}
```

And the following is the code to initialize the `KeycloakConfigResolver` bean.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(HeaderBasedConfigResolver.class)
public KeycloakConfigResolver keycloakConfigResolver() {
    return new HeaderBasedConfigResolver();
}
```

But when I initialize the KeycloakConfigResolver Bean with the default Implementation KeycloakSpringBootConfigResolver, it authenticates normally. I wonder how I could implement multi-tenancy in keycloak using credentials

Comment: To track the issue, I also posted it on github: https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/issues/15391

Comment: Do anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 1):

[Keycloak adapters for spring are deprecated](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/discussions/10187). Instead, use `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server` (to secure `@RestController` and `@Controller` with `@ResponseBody`) or `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client` (to secure server-side rendered UI with Thymeleaf, JSF or whatever). If you don't know how, you can refer to Spring-boot official doc or to [those tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) I wrote.

To configure multi-tenancy with `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`, you'll have to provide a custom `JwtIssuerAuthenticationManagerResolver` bean capable of resolving the right authnetication-manager based on the `iss` claim in the access-token:

```java
http.oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2 -> oauth2.authenticationManagerResolver(authenticationManagerResolver))
```

In the same repo as the one holding the tutorials, I propose thin wrappers around `spring-boot-starter-oauth2-resource-server`. Those designed for JWT decoder support multi-tenancy definition from properties:

```xml
<!-- instead of keycloak adapters for Spring -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.c4-soft.springaddons</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-addons-webmvc-jwt-resource-server</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.8</version>
</dependency>
```

```java
@EnableMethodSecurity
public static class SecurityConfig {
}
```

```
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/realm1
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[0].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-confidential.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].location=https://localhost:8443/realms/realm2
com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.issuers[1].authorities.claims=realm_access.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-public.roles,resource_access.spring-addons-confidential.roles

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.cors[0].path=/greet

com.c4-soft.springaddons.security.permit-all=/actuator/health/readiness,/actuator/health/liveness
```

Comment: I'm curious why this did not answer your question nor helped you in any manner.