# Authorization with two Keycloaks and shared tokens

Tags: java, api, authentication, keycloak, access-token

I have the following situation. Some of the users are authorized to the my backend service with Direct Access Grants, but those who are administrators are on a second Keycloak with another client and realm, and I need to be able to get valid tokens for the first Keycloak for them as well. I registered the second Keycloak with the administrators in the Identity Provider of the first one and if I use the normal web work flow from the first one I can log in with an admin user but I stay in the page of the first Keycloak and I can't get the tokens of that user in my backend. If I try to change the redirect_uri, I get an error that it is not allowed, even though I put * in the client of the second one. These are my settings for both Keycloaks.

How can I get a token for a user from the second Keycloak that is also valid in the first Keycloak?

First Keycloak Identity Provider settings:

```
  "identityProviders": [
{
  "alias": "keycloak-oidc",
  "internalId": "c3a3b1db-65ee-49df-b517-bfba6c355696",
  "providerId": "keycloak-oidc",
  "enabled": true,
  "updateProfileFirstLoginMode": "on",
  "trustEmail": false,
  "storeToken": true,
  "addReadTokenRoleOnCreate": true,
  "authenticateByDefault": false,
  "linkOnly": false,
  "firstBrokerLoginFlowAlias": "first broker login",
  "config": {
    "userInfoUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:909/auth/realms/vrp-realm-adm/protocol/openid-connect/userinfo",
    "hideOnLoginPage": "false",
    "clientId": "vrp-client-adm",
    "tokenUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:909/auth/realms/vrp-realm-adm/protocol/openid-connect/token",
    "acceptsPromptNoneForwardFromClient": "false",
    "backchannelSupported": "false",
    "useJwksUrl": "true",
    "loginHint": "false",
    "authorizationUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:909/auth/realms/vrp-realm-adm/protocol/openid-connect/auth",
    "clientAuthMethod": "client_secret_post",
    "logoutUrl": "http://host.docker.internal:909/auth/realms/vrp-realm-adm/protocol/openid-connect/logout",
    "syncMode": "IMPORT",
    "clientSecret": "**********"
  }
}
```

Second Keycloak client settings:

```
{
  "id": "f873a96c-6468-4737-b576-bdf610fb9597",
  "clientId": "vrp-client-adm",
  "rootUrl": "http://localhost:808",
  "adminUrl": "http://localhost:808",
  "surrogateAuthRequired": false,
  "enabled": true,
  "alwaysDisplayInConsole": false,
  "clientAuthenticatorType": "client-secret",
  "secret": "**********",
  "redirectUris": [
    "*"
  ],
  "webOrigins": [
    "*"
  ],
  "notBefore": 0,
  "bearerOnly": false,
  "consentRequired": false,
  "standardFlowEnabled": false,
  "implicitFlowEnabled": true,
  "directAccessGrantsEnabled": true,
  "serviceAccountsEnabled": true,
  "publicClient": false,
  "frontchannelLogout": false,
  "protocol": "openid-connect",
  "attributes": {
    "saml.multivalued.roles": "false",
    "saml.force.post.binding": "false",
    "frontchannel.logout.session.required": "false",
    "oauth2.device.authorization.grant.enabled": "false",
    "backchannel.logout.revoke.offline.tokens": "false",
    "saml.server.signature.keyinfo.ext": "false",
    "use.refresh.tokens": "true",
    "oidc.ciba.grant.enabled": "true",
    "backchannel.logout.session.required": "true",
    "client_credentials.use_refresh_token": "false",
    "saml.client.signature": "false",
    "require.pushed.authorization.requests": "false",
    "saml.allow.ecp.flow": "false",
    "saml.assertion.signature": "false",
    "id.token.as.detached.signature": "false",
    "client.secret.creation.time": "1668867137",
    "saml.encrypt": "false",
    "saml.server.signature": "false",
    "exclude.session.state.from.auth.response": "false",
    "saml.artifact.binding": "false",
    "saml_force_name_id_format": "false",
    "tls.client.certificate.bound.access.tokens": "false",
    "acr.loa.map": "{}",
    "saml.authnstatement": "false",
    "display.on.consent.screen": "false",
    "token.response.type.bearer.lower-case": "false",
    "saml.onetimeuse.condition": "false"
  },
  "authenticationFlowBindingOverrides": {},
  "fullScopeAllowed": true,
  "nodeReRegistrationTimeout": -1,
  "protocolMappers": [
    {
      "id": "6e02e265-af71-4af2-9253-ac26051053a4",
      "name": "Client IP Address",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientAddress",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientAddress",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2173ad2e-953d-401a-816b-19d920f7fa16",
      "name": "Client ID",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientId",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientId",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "2aad6645-174c-4dcd-b711-4eb388dbac3e",
      "name": "Client Host",
      "protocol": "openid-connect",
      "protocolMapper": "oidc-usersessionmodel-note-mapper",
      "consentRequired": false,
      "config": {
        "user.session.note": "clientHost",
        "id.token.claim": "true",
        "access.token.claim": "true",
        "claim.name": "clientHost",
        "jsonType.label": "String"
      }
    }
  ],
  "defaultClientScopes": [
    "web-origins",
    "acr",
    "profile",
    "roles",
    "email"
  ],
  "optionalClientScopes": [
    "address",
    "phone",
    "offline_access",
    "microprofile-jwt"
  ]
}
```

Comment: I think what you might need is the "identity provider federation" feature or Keycloak, where you can connect several identity providers. (Don't necessarily have to be all Keycloak instances.) Found the docs (https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/#_identity_broker) but didn't try it for myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found next article who helped me to do auth process throw 2 keycloak instances

https://www.jessym.com/articles/stateless-oauth2-social-logins-with-spring-boot

Answer (score 1):

The post by trotman23 in this thread may help
https://keycloak.discourse.group/t/unable-to-retrieve-upstream-identity-providers-original-token/2267/2

Answer (score 0):

I detailed how to achieve multi-tenancy on a Spring resource-server with JWT decoder in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74791753/619830).

All the authorization-servers being Keycloak is not important. The solution I proposed there is having resource-server(s) accept identities emitted by more than just one issuer (use a list of trusted issuers instead). So clients or users can choose their preferred authorization-server in that list.

Comment: Thanks, but the customer's requirement is that admins are authenticated by the 2nd Keycloak. Multitenancy doesn't work for me

Comment: I might need your definition of multi-tenancy to understand. What I refer to is perfectly compatible with admins being authenticated by an authorization-server (tenant `A`) and other users by a different one (tenant `B`)

Comment: Identity federation is required only when when one authorization-server emits opaque tokens or does not include your resource-server in its audience.